# Jquery mobile data-icons are not showing on windows device. (Phonegap)

Tags: jquery-ui, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build my first application on windows platform using phone gap. I am able to run my application but I'm not able to see any icon like back button, menu button icon in both emulator and device. How can we get the data-icons in page header.

CSS:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id ="pichartimg">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
          <h3>Pie Chart</h3>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" id="change-color">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id='canvasDivpie' class = "sidebar"></div>
 </div>
```

I'm not able to see the back button in page header. What is the issue and how to get icons.

Comment: `<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Back</a>`

Comment: NO It doesn't come from the above code. I'm using phonegap2.9 and windows 7 phone. Please help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this too. My experience ist, that it's important to have the correct order in your Javascript inclusions.

I suggest you to first include your CSS. Then right after in the following order:

1. jQuery
2. Jquery Mobile
3. Cordova
4. any other Javascript

Done so the below example should display a button in your header with an icon on the right side:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
  <h1>Some Headline</h1>
  <a href="#main" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I have same issue: jQM 1.4.5 / jQ 1.11.3 and I don't see panel menu icons, collapsible-set icons... in Cordova build app!? :/